# How to use require.js with complicated source tree, or import something else from CommonJS'es main.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd, commonjs

My JS code is `Backbone.js` based, so I think it is a good idea to separate "classes" with this logic as shown on picture (though I'm not sure where to place templates - in this packages or in global `templates` folder, and do not mind `main.js` - it is not related to `CommonJS` packages) :

[image]

Now since there is fairly lot of them - I've decided to use `require.js` to deal with this bunch of `<script src=...` tags but got stuck with `app.js` config file (which is the only one that I include like this -

`<script data-main="/static/js/app.js" src="/static/js/libmin/require.js"></script>`

What do I mean with *stuck* - of course I can iterate all this js files in `require` statement using names like `PlayerApp/PlayerAppController.js`, or using [paths](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) directive (not sure if it will make the code look not that ugly), but it would be cool if I can use something like python's `from package import *`, and of course there is no such thing in `require.js`.

The most similar thing is [packages](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) directive, but seems like it allows you to import only `main.js` from each package, so then the question is - what is the most correct way to load other files of concrete package from `CommonJS`'s `main.js`? I have even found a way to determine current .js file's name and path - [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807441/1531116), and given that I can make up other files names in current package(if I will keep naming them with the same pattern), but still do not know how to import them from `main.js`

**Edit:**

There might be an opinion that it is not very clear what exactly am I asking, so let me get this straight: how on Earth do I import a huge amount of javascript files with that project structure in the most nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-understanding the purpose of a module loader.  `require.js` is not there to make it easy for you to import all of your packages into the current namespace (i. e. the browser).  It is there to make it easy to import everything you *need* to run `app.js` (based on your `data-main` attribute).  Don't try to `import *` - instead, just `import thingYouNeed`.

#### Configuration

What you will want to do is set up your [`require.config()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) call with all the necessary paths for libraries like Backbone that don't support AMD and then update *your* code to explicitly declare its dependencies:

```
require.config({
  // Not *needed* - will be derived from data-main otherwise
  baseUrl: '/static/js/app',
  paths: {
    // A map of module names to paths (without the .js)
    backbone: '../libmin/backbone',
    underscore: '../libmin/underscore',
    jquery: '../libmin/jquery.min',
    jqueryui.core: '../libmin/jquery.ui.core'
    // etc.
  }
  shim: {
    // A map of module names to configs
    backbone: {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    jquery: {
      exports: 'jQuery'
    },
    // Since jQuery UI does not export
    // its own name we can just provide
    // a deps array without the object
    'jqueryui.core': ['jquery']
  }
});
```

#### Dependencies

You will want to update *your* code to actually use modules and declare your dependencies:

```
// PlayerAppModel.js
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({modelStuff: 'here'});
});

// PlayerAppView.js
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({viewStuff: 'here'});
});

// PlayerAppController.js
define(['./PlayerAppModel', './PlayerAppView'],
function(Model, View) {
    // Do things with model and view here
    // return a Controller function of some kind
    return function Controller() {
      // Handle some route or other
    };
});
```

Now, when you `require(['PlayerApp/PlayerAppController'], function(Controller) {})` requirejs will automatically load jQuery, underscore, and Backbone for you.  If you never actually *use* mustache.js then it will never be loaded (and when you optimize your code using the r.js compiler, the extra code will be ignored there as well).

Comment: Yeah, looks like I did not have a right example like yours or [this](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)... Also, can you please tell me what is the difference between `define` without first argument and `require`?

Comment: @scythargon - `require` is the `main` of your application - it is the entry point which loads everything else and kicks off execution of the app.  [`define` (no matter how it is invoked)](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) is for declaring a module - you should avoid having "import time" side effects in your `define` callbacks, but your `require` callback should be full of side effects (if that makes more sense).

Comment: yep, thanks a lot. Now it makes sense, alongside with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17366073/1531116)