# NetSuite auth.ChangePassword

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to reset password with following script

```
/*
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
require(['N/auth'],
 function(auth) {
 function changePass() {

                var password = '111';

                auth.changePassword({
                    currentPassword: password,
                    newPassword: '222'
                });

                 return 'ChangeDone';
 }


});
```

and i run it as RESTlet in SOAPUI

i receive this error:

error code: REFERENCE_ERROR error message:ReferenceError: "require" is not defined

Help Please!!

Comment: Looks like require.js not loaded at that moment. Probably you should check the order of your scripts loading

Comment: hi, thank you. can you please direct me or send any docs about it? please

Comment: Have you loaded requirejs? https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `require` with `define`.

See [RequireJs - Define vs Require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366073/requirejs-define-vs-require).

Due to the way NetSuite uses the AMD framework, it can be confusing to follow from the documentation, but in general you use `define()` in a script and only use `require()` when testing functions in a browser console.

Comment: error code: REFERENCE_ERROR error message:ReferenceError: "define" is not defined

Comment: I have to say this isn't the conclusion I would have jumped to. More likely OP has found a snippet on the internet and doesn't realise they need to load the requirejs script. Besides, I thought `define` and `require` came in the same package.

Comment: @DavidKnipe you're right.  I was answering from my experience of NetSuite, and the fact that the script above is clearly written as a NetSuite script.  Now looking closer I see that he's running it in SOAPUI, which I don't know anything about. Looking at the NetSuite documentation I also see this is the sample they give for their N/auth module.  Not sure why OP's attempting to test it with SOAPUI as you can run these through the NetSuite framework, but not loading require.js does seem like the problem (NetSuite handles all that for you if you use their system).