# Getting angular to manually bootstrap using grunt and r.js/requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs, amd, r.js

I am trying to integrate requirejs into an existing project, which runs on a node/grunt stack. I want to use the r.js optimizer to concat everything together and noodle through dependencies to do its magic as well.

I am able to get r.js to build a single .js file, and there are no errors... but nothing happens. I set breakpoints in my code, but nothing is getting kicked off - the app never actually *runs* the bootstrap.js file. I have tried putting the bootstrap.js in an immediate function, and of course it does run then, but the dependencies are not loaded yet (it seems). What am I missing here?

File structure:

```
 app
 -> modules
 - -> common
 - - -> auth.js // contains an auth call that needs to return before I bootstrap angular
 -> app.js
 -> index.html
 config
 -> main.js
 node_modules
 vendor
 -> angular/jquery/require/domready/etc
 gruntfile.js
```

gruntfile requirejs task:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      name: 'app',
      out: 'build/js/app.js',
      baseUrl: 'app',
      mainConfigFile: 'config/main.js',
      optimize: "none"
    }
  }
},
```

main.js config:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'bootstrap':      '../app/bootstrap',
    'domReady':      '../vendor/requirejs-domready/domReady',
    'angular':       '../vendor/angular/angular',
    'jquery':        '../vendor/jquery/jquery.min',
    'app':           'app',
    'auth':          '../app/modules/common/auth',
    requireLib:      '../vendor/requirejs/require'
  },
  include: ['domReady', 'requireLib'],

  shim: {
    'angular': {
      exports: 'angular'
    }
  },

  // kick start application
  deps: ['bootstrap']
});
```

app.js:

```
define([
  'angular',
  'jquery',
], function (angular, $) {
  'use strict';

  $( "#container" ).css("visibility","visible");

  return angular.module('app');
});
```

bootstrap.js:

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app',
    'jquery',
    'auth'
], function (require, angular, app, $, auth) {

    var Authentication = auth.getInstance();
    .. do auth stuff...

      if (Authentication.isAuthorized) {
        require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
       });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a main point of entry into your application; here it would be `app.js`, but all you are doing in that file is defining that files dependencies and not actually loading any code. You need to change your code to this:

```
require([
  'angular',
  'jquery',
], function (angular, $) {
  'use strict';

  $( "#container" ).css("visibility","visible");

  return angular.module('app');
});
```

See this thread for more details on [the difference between define and require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507606/when-to-use-require-and-when-to-use-define).

Comment: That was it - thank you very much Ben! I appreciate the fast answer!