# RequireJS: How do I pass variables from one file to another?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using require with backbone + backbone-forms. I'm currently using RequireJS to seperate code into multiple files. I have models stored in separate files and want to keep form validators separately.

However, I am unable to access variables defined in one files, in another file that depends on this one. What I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: isEmptyName is not defined`. `isEmptyName` is defined in validators and used in model. Any feedback about RequireJS config is also appreciated.

My config:

```
requirejs.config({

//By default load any module IDs from js/lib

baseUrl: 'js',

paths: {
     jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        app: 'lib/app', 
     wizard: 'lib/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min',
  bootstrap: 'lib/bootstrap.min',
 underscore: 'lib/underscore-min',
   backbone: 'lib/backbone-min',
backboneForms: 'lib/backbone-forms.min',
langSwitcher: 'lib/lang',
     cookie: 'lib/cookie',
 datepicker: 'lib/bootstrap-datepicker',
       mask: 'lib/jquery.maskedinput.min',
 validators: 'modules/validators',  

  // models

personalData: 'models/personal-data',
addressData: 'models/address-data',
   workData: 'models/work-data',
productsData: 'models/products-data',
statmentData: 'models/statment-data',    

     model: 'models/form',
collection: 'collections/form',
      view: 'views/form',

     setup: 'setup',
      send: 'send',

},
    shim: {
    'underscore': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: '_'
    },  
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'backbone'
    },

    // all model needs to go within one collection

    'bootstrap' : ['jquery'],
    'wizard': ['jquery'],
    'backboneForms': ['backbone'],
    'validators': ['backbone','mask'],
    'personalData' : ['backbone','backboneForms','validators'],
    'addressData': ['backbone','backboneForms'],
    'workData': ['backbone','backboneForms'],
    'statmentData': ['backbone','backboneForms'],

    //'collection': ['backbone','backboneForms','personalData'],
    //'view': ['backbone','backboneForms','personalData']
 } 
});
```

Beginning of validators.js

```
require(['backbone','backboneForms'], function(){


var lettersOnly = /^[A-Za-zęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]+$/;
var lettersOnlyDash = /^[A-Za-zęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ\-]+$/;
var err = {};
var errCh = {};
var errFormat = {};

var isEmptyName = function(value){
err = { message: 'Wpisz imię.'};
if (value.length === 0) return err;
};
```

Beginning of model.js that needs the validators in validators.js

```
require(['backbone','backboneForms','mask','validators'], function(backbone,backboneForms,mask,validators){

var PersonalData = Backbone.Model.extend({

schema: {
    first_name:{ 
        title: 'Imię',            
        validators: [isEmptyName, isLetter, minCharCount] //Accessing validators.js members here...
    }, ...
```

Comment: You need to define the validators as AMD module that returns the isEmptyName in order to use it

Comment: While the question is quite similar to another, I think it will be helpful for people new to RequireJS to have this around as a 'link' to the more technically worded question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507606/when-to-use-require-and-when-to-use-define)

Comment: Thanks for help.It had some impact but I'm getting a different error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" how would I rewrite this function in order to make it work?

Comment: Where does this error occur - line, file, etc. This means that whatever `var` you're trying to get the `length` of is undefined, which could be due to a variety of reasons. EDIT: If it's in `value.length === 0` check if `value` is passed in by the caller.

Comment: True. Error shows in validator.js I think it is fired there but it has no idea what the "value" is.

Comment: I might be stating the obvious, but Chrome/Webkit's javascript debugging is quite robust. Open the Sources tab and open up validator.js, place a breakpoint at that line. The Call Stack on the right pane should help you figure out who is calling that...

Comment: Cool, sometimes it's good to state the obvious. Got something like this [link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/280paw0.jpg)

Comment: ok no worries I used your explanation and it works. Many thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're using `require` when what you really need is `define`. From [When should I use require() and when to use define()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507606/when-to-use-require-and-when-to-use-define),

> With define you register a module in require.js that you than can
>   depend on in other module definitions or require statements. With
>   require you "just" load/use a module or javascript file that can be
>   loaded by require.js.

---

So here, you have some variables that are defined in one file, but are required to be accessed in another file. Seems like a 'Module', doesn't it? So now, you have two ways of using this file as a module:

1. Conform to AMD-ness
2. Conform to chaotic javascript global variable-ness

### Using the AMD Approach

`validators.js` is now a module. Anybody wishing to use 'validator functions' can depend on this module to provide it for them. That is,

```
define(['backbone','backboneForms'], function(){

  var lettersOnly = /^[A-Za-zęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]+$/;

  var isEmptyName = function(value){
  err = { message: 'Wpisz imię.'};
  if (value.length === 0) return err;

  return {
    someVariable: lettersOnly,
    someFunction: isEmptyName
  }
};
```

You'll notice that the `require` has been replaced with `define`. Now, when somebody (model) depends on validator.js, they can access their dependencies as follows

```
require(['backbone','backboneForms','mask','validators'], 
  function(backbone, backboneForms, mask, validators) {

    var isEmptyNameReference = validators.someFunction;
    ...
```

### Using `shim`

Check [Requirejs why and when to use shim config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config), which references [this link](http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-requirejs-dependency-management/) which says,

> if we were to just add the backbone.js file to our project and list
>   Backbone as a dependency from one of our modules, it wouldn’t work.
>   RequireJS will load backbone.js, but nothing in backbone.js registers
>   itself as a module with RequireJS. RequireJS will throw up its hands
>   and say something like, “Well, I loaded the file, but I didn’t find
>   any module in there.”

So, you could have your validator.js populate a global `Validator` namespace, and still use it the way we used it in the example above.

```
function(){
  var lettersOnly = /^[A-Za-zęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]+$/;
  var isEmptyName = function(value){
    err = { message: 'Wpisz imię.'};
    if (value.length === 0) return err;

  Globals.Validator = {
    someVariable: lettersOnly,
    someFunction: isEmptyName
  }
}();
```

Your config.js would then be,

```
shim: {
    'validator': {
        deps: ['backbone','backboneForms'],
        exports: 'Globals.Validator'
    },
  ...
```

Note that you can alias the namespace as you wish, but the alias is just a reference to the existing global object/namespace. This is helpful if you have, say, `Foo.Bar.Foobar` as your namespace, but want to refer to it as `FB`. Shimming, hence, is a way for non-AMD libraries to adapt to AMD usage. **In this case, option 1 should be sufficient.**

Comment: Basically the best what you can get from StackOverflow community. Many thanks mate. You're the best. Answer is descriptive and I've learned a lot. Many, many thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: hey I am following your suggestion but still not be able to do.
Here is my  [ question] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668293/accessing-variable-from-different-filesmodule-using-requirejs