# Accessing variable from different files(module) using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, canjs

I am trying to make MVC structure of application in canjs. For that I am using requireJS to separate the code in different file.

I have searched in google and i am  following this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/) but in that tutorail I dont find to access module variables in different modules. therefore I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649078/requirejs-how-do-i-pass-variables-from-one-file-to-another) method to do so.

But I cannot achieve that. 
This is my code:

requirejsconfig.js file :

```
  requirejs.config({
   paths :{
    enforceDefine: true,
    waitSeconds : 0,
    jquery      : "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min", 
    main        : "view/main",
    player      : "view/player",
    PlayerModel : "/models/PlayerModel",
    hbs         : "/models/view/js/handlebars",
    fixture     : "/models/view/js/can.fixture", 
    can         : "/models/view/js/can.jquery"

 }
});
```

main.js :

```
require(["player"],function(player){
    player.PlayerModel();
 });
```

I want to use that model methods in my controller.

player.js :

```
 define(['PlayerModel'],function(){

     function PlayerModel(){   
        var Player = PlayerModel.Player;
         Players =can.Control({ defaults :{view:view/players.hbs' }},{
            init: function(){
                this.element.html(can.view(this.options.view, {
                    players: this.options.players
                }));
            }
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.when(Player.findAll()).then(
         function(playersResponse){
            var players = playersResponse[0];      

            new Players('.players', {
                players: players
             });
         });
    });
  }
});
```

PlayerModel.js:

```
   define(function(){

        var Player = can.Model({
            findAll: 'GET /models/players.json',
            findOne: 'GET /players.json/{id}'
        });
        return {
            Player:Player
        }
    });
```

Every file is being loaded (saw in network tab-chrome devtools) but nothing is being populated in output.

Can anybody help me ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like inside  `PlayerModel()`, you're accessing `PlayerModel.Player`. Doesn't look like you've defined that anywhere.

Comment: I have defined it. updated my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrying on with what @ekuusela said, restructure the code in `Player.js` in this format:

```
define(['PlayerModel'],function(){
  function PlayerModel(){ ... }
  return {
    PlayerModel: PlayerModel
  }
});
```

---

#### What's happening

Internally, two conventions are followed when defining modules. These relate to:

1. What the module is called (its label)
2. What this label represents.

#### Labeling Modules

The filename is taken as the module's name (unless `shim` is used, like you have). In other words, the `define(['Module_Name'] ...)`, which is how I would normally read that line, can more accurately be read as a `define(['Module_Path_Or_Shim_Symbol_Name' ...)`

#### What Is This 'Module' Anyway

A module isn't magic - it is just a specially labeled map to a function. This map is maintained by RequireJS and probably looks similar to this:

```
var ModuleMap = {
  'Player' : function (...) { ... },
  'PlayerModel' : function (...) { ... }
};
```

Every time a module is accessed, through a `require` or `define` call, this map is accessed, and the relevant function found. However, that isn't enough - what we want is the stuff that is defined *within the function* - the fundamental concept of modules is that everything inside them has Module Function Scope, and is not exposed outside. So, to gain access to this "stuff", the RequireJS brain does the only thing it *can* do with a function - execute it.

```
var playerReference = require('Player');
```

*Note that I've used the CommonJS notation of requiring modules, which is more readable for our current purpose.*

So, in the code you posted, the module function has **defined and declared PlayerModel** as a function, but has not **exposed it**. Since the line `player.PlayerModel()` expects the module to return an object with a property named `PlayerModel` that refers to your function, the logical return value of the module is:

```
var exposedModuleReference = { PlayerModel: PlayerModel };
return exposedModuleReference;
```

Note that this means the name with which the function is exposed can be different from the function name itself. For example, the following code will **also** work without any changes anywhere else:

```
define(['PlayerModel'],function(){
  function PlayerModelConstructor(){ ... }
  return {
    PlayerModel: PlayerModelConstructor
  }
});
```

#### An Interesting Addition

So, executing a module function and assigning that return value to a reference is one part of what RequireJS's brain does. The other part is, it then updates this map so it now looks like this:

```
var ModuleMap = {
  'Player' : { PlayerModel: PlayerModelConstructor },
  'PlayerModel' : function (...) { ... }
};
```

This means that code written in module functions gets **executed at most one time.**

Comment: thanx for clear my concept over modules. It is very clear and helpful answer.I am appreciate for this answer!! Thnx once again.!!

Answer (score 1):

You define the function `PlayerModel` inside `player.js` and then require a module called `PlayerModel` there but don't assign the required module to any variable. You should first clean up your code, possibly rename some of your modules and move functions around.

Here, you try to access the function `PlayerModel` in the module `player`, but the module factory function in `player.js` doesn't return anything:

```
require(["player"],function(player){
   player.PlayerModel();
});
```

What gets assigned to the function parameter `player` is only whatever you return from the function that defines the module. (If you would define a module as an object then that object would be the argument.)

Comment: Thnx for the answer!!